# How to reference from drawable to style

Tags: android, image, reference, themes, styles

My app with tabs has two themes. In each theme tabs have different images in selected and unselected state. How I can properly reference to image by theme?

For example. I have in themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<style name="LightTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="tabShows">@drawable/ic_tab_shows_unselected_light</item>
    <item name="tabShowsSelected">@drawable/ic_tab_shows_selected_light</item>
    <item name="tabNews">@drawable/ic_tab_news_selected_light</item>
    <item name="tabNewsSelected">@drawable/ic_tab_news_unselected_light</item>
</style>

<style name="DarkTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
    <item name="tabShows">@drawable/ic_tab_shows_unselected_dark</item>
    <item name="tabShowsSelected">@drawable/ic_tab_shows_selected_dark</item>
    <item name="tabNews">@drawable/ic_tab_news_selected_dark</item>
    <item name="tabNewsSelected">@drawable/ic_tab_news_unselected_dark</item>
   </style>
```

Also I have a tab_shows.xml and tab_news.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item  android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_shows_selected_light"/>
<item  android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_shows_unselected_light" />
```

How I can reference to needed image in selector according to current theme?
This not work for me

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item  android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="?tabShowsSelected"/>
<item  android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="?tabShows" />
```

In layout files this works, I mean reference to style via ?styleName

Answer (score 5):

Build your style `A` and style `B`

in your case you put `android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_shows_selected_light"` instead of background (I just copied snipets from my code)
    
            #000

```
    <style name="styleB">
        <item name="android:background">#000</item>
    </style>
```

your theme A

```
<style name="Theme.A">
        <item name="pageBackground">@style/styleA</item>
    </style>
```

theme B

```
<style name="Theme.Blue">
        <item name="pageBackground">@style/styleB</item>
    </style>
```

in your attr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="pageBackground" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

finally in your widget you do `style="?pageBackground"`

Answer (score 3):

You can find your answer here
http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html

**Edit**
(Additional information by Lukap in comments)

1. Define one or more themes in `themes.xml` and set the definitions of your styles there.
2. Define custom attributes, a.k.a. custom styles, in `attrs.xml`.
3. Describe what the values of your custom styles are in `styles.xml`.

But you will need read more about the `attrs.xml`

```
<item name="android:background">? android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator</item> 
</style>
```

Instead, we are referring to the value of some other attribute – `activatedBackgroundIndicator` – from our inherited theme. Whatever the theme defines as being the `activatedBackgroundIndicator` is what our background should be.