# Exception when using custom attributes in layout

Tags: android, android-theme

I have defined some custom attributes that I want to use throughout my app, which work fine when running through Eclipse, but throws an exception *sometimes* when the APK has been built and distributed. Below is the stack trace of the exception:

```
W/dalvikvm( 2521): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f44300)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at com.myapp.android.ui.fragment.CustomDialogFragmentImpl.onCreateView(CustomDialogFragmentImpl.java:74)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at com.myapp.android.ui.fragment.SupportCustomDialogFragment.onCreateView(SupportCustomDialogFragment.java:41)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): ... 23 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x2
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3342)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:427)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:101)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:97)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2521): ... 26 more
```

Here is the view at line #13:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="12dp"
    android:paddingLeft="?attr/listItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="?attr/listItemPaddingRight" >
```

Here is my defined attributes:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyAppTheme">
    <attr name="listItemPaddingLeft" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="listItemPaddingRight" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="listItemHeight" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="listHeaderHeight" format="dimension" />
</declare-styleable>
```

And lastly, here is my theme:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="listItemPaddingLeft">22dp</item>
    <item name="listItemPaddingRight">22dp</item>
    <item name="listItemHeight">43dp</item>
    <item name="listHeaderHeight">73dp</item>
</style>
```

Does anyone see any problems with the way I've defined things, or can offer an explanation as to why this would work when built locally, but not when the APK is signed? My device is the Galaxy Nexus, which worked fine locally and with the signed APK, but the Galaxy S3 does not work with the signed APK (wasn't able to test it locally).

Comment: similar issue :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598349/android-unsupportedoperationexception-cant-convert-to-color-type-0x2

Comment: @AliImran My issue is dealing with attributes and styles that I've defined, not Android attributes and styles that I've overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the currently (used)set theme is one which contains your custom attribute. You can set it in the manifest file or just set it explicitly before inflating the layout:

```
setTheme(R.style.MyAppTheme)
setContentView(R.layout.MyActivity);
```