# UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x1

Tags: android, android-styles

I am running my application in nexus 7 with api 21.When app opens from background 
it force close with following exception

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x1
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:404)
```

Log cat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.online.Androidv2/com.online.Androidv2.PagerActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x1
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x1
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:404)
        at android.app.Activity.onApplyThemeResource(Activity.java:3674)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:140)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:85)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2244)
        at   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I am using the theme AppTheme for the application.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base" />

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_color_dark</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Color values is

```
<color name="theme_color">#b61702</color>
<color name="theme_color_dark">#a70001</color>
```

I can't find the reason for this.Any help?

Comment: Hi Sunny, can you paste more of the LogCat? It does not seem as if this is your root cause, I am not seeing any errors in the posted XML.

Comment: just a suggestion ,try  and changing `@android:color/white` to `#FFFFFF`

Comment: @MattClark i Edited my question with logcat messages

Comment: Well I'll be damned... Hmm... Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9676533/1790644) help?

Comment: color, what? is it a style attribute? search for that again. it may be the **android:textColor** or **android:background** that you are looking for.

Comment: I am using appcompat v21

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26440502/1576416  refer this answer or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26447144/1576416

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't convert to color: type=0x2 error when inflating layout in fragment but only on Samsung Galaxy and Note 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986204/cant-convert-to-color-type-0x2-error-when-inflating-layout-in-fragment-but-onl)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same problem, After I check my code, I found I used **@style/custom** to set **android:textColor** in my style xml file. 
Then I just refer @color/custom to android:textColor, error disappeared.

And error happened in Android API 18, API 23 works well.

useful link: [java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958179/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-cant-convert-to-color-type-0x1)

Comment: Here's another useful link: [Can't convert to color: type=0x2 error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34279007/383414)

Comment: [... and another ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041537/how-to-reference-style-attributes-from-a-drawable/13471695#13471695)