# Error inflating class EditText in Android Tablet version 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-4.4-kitkat, android-inflate, android-textinputlayout

Hi all my application is working fine but I am getting a crash coming in Android Tablet with `version 4.4.2` but don't know why as application is working fine in other versions perfectly. Error i am getting :

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error
>   inflating class EditText
>        android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java) Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error
>   inflating class EditText
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
>          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java) Caused by java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension:
>   type=0x1
>          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:464)
>          at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:972)
>          at android.widget.EditText.(EditText.java:60)
>          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.(AppCompatEditText.java:60)
>          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.(AppCompatEditText.java:56)
>          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:112)
>          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1008)
>          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1067)
>          at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
>          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)

I am using `Edittext` with `TextInputLayout` some code of android `xml` :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout"
            >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="Notes"
                android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_size"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**dimens.xml**

```
<dimen name="edit_text_size">22sp</dimen>
```

line #38: where i have defined first Editext in my layout there is inflating issue :

[image]

In `res/value/styles` and `res/value-sw720dp` i have defined style for hint text :

```
<style name="TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/view_green</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

I can't find why this crash is coming! please help

Comment: Which line is you line #38 from the given snippet?

Comment: Are you sure you have the `edit_text_size` dimension defined in every `res/values*/` folder? Particularly in `res/values/`.

Comment: can you post your build.gradle file

Comment: @vidulaJ in java code line#38 is `setContentView` in `onCreate`

Comment: That line refers to a line in the xml file. I am asking of which line on the given snippet. There are 14 lines in the given xml and which line it is?

Comment: @MikeM. yes i have defined `edit_text_size` in `dimens`

Comment: Right, but in which folder? There can be multiple `res/values*/` folders. You need to make sure to have a value for that in the `dimens.xml` in specifically `res/values/`.

Comment: @vidulaJ please check screenshot i have added in my question

Comment: please post the hint style that you defined in: `TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout`

Comment: @MikeM. yes i have did defined edittext dimension in both folders  res/values/ and res/values-sw720dp/

Comment: @hakim i have edited my question please check

Comment: thank you, that part of style is not help much, since it child style of `TextAppearance.App`, please  try remove style attribute `         app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout"` in TextInputLayout is it work?

Comment: Have you tried "TextAppearanceAppTextInputLayout" (removed '.') for style name? Error log line number sometimes show different line which causes error. (Error may happen before EditText line.)

Comment: @Kapil Rajput have you defined com.android.support:design:* in build.gradle file?

Comment: @vidulaJ yes i have defined it, in all version rather that android 4.4 app is running fine

Comment: See the accepted answer in this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385055/error-inflating-class-edittext-on-creating-textinputlayout-on-android-4-4-2

Answer (score 1):

I saw this error on your logcat

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1`

Try changing `android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_size"/>` into any value

Comment: i did defined edit text size in `dimens` already please see my edited question

Answer (score 0):

try to clean your project and rebuild it, notice whether have extra Invaild char around

Comment: i had tried and getting crashes on release build too

Comment: any devices crashes?