# Change only one state (the default state) of an ImageButton background

Tags: java, android, android-theme, android-selector

I'd like to change the background for an image button.  Basically the image I have looks great on a transparent background and a bit lousy when there are a bunch of them all with a non-transparent background.

This should be easy - just change the `android:background` on the button to a transparent color (via a drawable):
click_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true"><color android:color="#FF008080" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true"><color android:color="#FF008080" />
    </item>
    <item><color android:color="#00000000" />
    </item>

</selector>
```

Then the button

```
<ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/players"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/click_background"
                android:contentDescription="@string/players"
                android:src="@drawable/speaker_tile" />
```

**The problem** is that I actually want to retain the `state_focussed` and `state_pressed` versions of the background (which I presume is derived from the theme).  I would like to have the background appear when the button is pressed or selected (and appear with the exact same colour/drawable) that would be used by the theme normally when a button is pressed would be helpful.

I was wondering if there is a way to do one of the following, but have so far been unable to find anything on either:

1. Define a selector that in some what inherits from another (similar to the way a theme can inherit from another).
2. Create an entirely new selector but have it's XML reference the color/drawable of the theme's  `state_focussed` and `state_pressed` used for an image button. **Edit: It looks like this option is out. I would have needed attributes, but you can't reference them from a drawable. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041537/how-to-reference-style-attributes-from-a-drawable)**

I'd like to do this in Declarative XML rather than Programmatic Java if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy the drawables used by the Android OS into your project and use them in your state-list drawable. You can find the images in `{android-sdk-directory}/platforms/android-##/data/res/drawable[-*dpi]`

**EDIT:**
If you go to `{android-sdk-directory}/platforms/android-##/data/res/values`, you'll find the `themes.xml` and `styles.xml` files used by Android. Using them you can figure out which drawables you'll be looking for.

For example, the default theme on newer versions of Android is `Theme.Holo`. This theme has a default style for ImageButtons declared like so:

`<item name="imageButtonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.ImageButton</item>`

In `styles.xml`, this style is defined as follows:

```
<style name="Widget.Holo.ImageButton" parent="Widget.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_default_holo_dark</item>
</style>
```

Thankfully the background attribute is right there defined in plain sight. Sometimes it's inherited from a parent style and you have to find that instead. In any case, here's the drawable (found in the `/drawable` directory since it's xml):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_focused_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_focused_holo_dark" />
<item
     android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_holo_dark" />
</selector>
```

So those are the drawables Android uses for the background of a standard ImageButton in the default (holo dark) theme.

Comment: Thanks, Any hints on which item in the drawable directory I'll be looking for?. There are rather a lot to search through.

Comment: I think ImageButton uses the same backgrounds as regular Button. It also depends on what platform level. On newer versions of Android, I think btn_default_{state}_holo_dark.9.png and btn_default_{state}_holo_light.9.png are the ones you are looking for, but I'm not positive. Usually I have to look through res/values/themes.xml and res/values/styles.xml in the platform resources to figure out exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Dunno on the down vote. I traced this (with your help) to btn_default_holo_dark.xml and its supporting images.  Would be grateful if you could add that to your answer.