# Custom view background using attrs causes crash

Tags: android, xml, exception, resources, stack-trace

I've been experimenting with styles in Android recently (and blatantly failed) trying to use attrs in custom view background resources. So basically, I want to make the user set a custom theme if he or she wants to. I have a main fragment which hosts a (support) ViewPager. Each page in the ViewPager gets inflated with a custom view using a custom background. The view's background points to a style reference which is basically a color justified by the selected theme.

**Attributes**

```
<attr name="designBase400" format="reference" />
<attr name="designBase500" format="reference" />
<attr name="designBase700" format="reference" />
```

**One of the few custom styles**

```
<style name="Theme.ColorScheme.Turquoise" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="designBase400">@color/design_base_400_turquoise</item>
    <item name="designBase500">@color/design_base_500_turquoise</item>
    <item name="designBase700">@color/design_base_700_turquoise</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem.DropDownItem</item>
</style>
```

**Corresponding colors**

```
<color name="design_base_500_turquoise">#009688</color>
<color name="design_base_700_turquoise">#00796B</color>
<color name="design_base_400_turquoise">#26A69A</color>
```

**Background resource**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="?attr/designBase400" />
</shape>
```

**The view using the background resource (only the important part)**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_entry_hour_container"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/entry_view_circle_dimen"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/entry_view_circle_dimen"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="false"
    android:background="@drawable/background_circle" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_entry_hour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/entry_view_hour_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I have a sample theme set in the ApplicationManifest.xml (say @style/Theme.ColorScheme.Turquoise) and the application crashes immediately, raising an InflationException. [The stack trace can be found here.](http://pastebin.com/dpeRcEEG) I don't have the foggiest idea on what could have went wrong.

Comment: Log says 01-11 16:48:25.511: E/AndroidRuntime(2037): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown> Something wrong at the 9th line of your XML

Comment: @oguzhand Well, the ninth line in my view resource is the first line in the view layout I included in my question. So basically #9 would refer to "<RelativeLayout"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually that is Android issue and it got fixed in Lollipop version, Please refer Google issue tracker link, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26251

So you should create separate drawable for each theme.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't see your reply before I finished my own response to my own question. So as far as I understood, this should be working in Android 5.0+ right? I run my applications on my tablet (using 4.4.2), so that's probably the reason why it didn't work. Thanks for your research nonetheless. Will check your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

So I *kind of* solved my problem using a reply on a [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041537/how-to-reference-style-attributes-from-a-drawable). Apparently, Android cannot handle attribute references in drawables (which is heavily inconvenient). Instead, one should create a reference to the background drawable, create a drawable for every theme and reference each one to the corresponding. Basically, I ended up with the following setup:

**Background resources**

[image: Backgroudn resource for every possible theme]

**Create new reference**

```
<attr name="designBase400" format="color" />
<attr name="designBase500" format="color" />
<attr name="designBase700" format="color" />

<!-- reference which points to the corresponding background resource -->
<attr name="circleBackground" format="reference" />
```

**Add the resource reference to the custom themes**

```
<style name="Theme.ColorScheme.Turquoise" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="designBase400">@color/design_base_400_turquoise</item>
    <item name="designBase500">@color/design_base_500_turquoise</item>
    <item name="designBase700">@color/design_base_700_turquoise</item>

    <item name="circleBackground">@drawable/background_circle_turquoise</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.ColorScheme.Blue" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="designBase400">@color/design_base_400_blue</item>
    <item name="designBase500">@color/design_base_500_blue</item>
    <item name="designBase700">@color/design_base_700_blue</item>

    <item name="circleBackground">@drawable/background_circle_blue</item>
</style> <!-- and so on ... -->
```

I'm not very satisfied with this solution since logically my first attempt should have been perfectly fine. I cannot say why Android doesn't accept attributes in drawables and I probably won't understand it either. Until someone is willing to enlighten me and provide a better solution I guess I have to stick to this.

Answer (score 0):

Change `format="reference"` to `format="color"` .

Comment: Sadly doesn't work either. Same error shows up, but [I found a link which says that it's not possible to reference attrs from a drawable resource.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041537/how-to-reference-style-attributes-from-a-drawable) It also suggests to create one resource for every theme. That can't be true, right?