# Can't convert to color: type=0x2 error when inflating layout in fragment but only on Samsung Galaxy and Note 4

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am working on a simple app with an activity and i use fragments.One screen with some elements. When i compile and run the app it works fine, except on Samsung Galaxy s3 and note 4. I don't get it from the stacktrace what is wrong.

```
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3253)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3327)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:336)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1973)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at com.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    ... 11 more
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    ... 25 more
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.initTitle(ActionBarView.java:1131)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.setDisplayOptions(ActionBarView.java:947)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(ActionBarView.java:392)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    ... 28 more
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    ... 38 more
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:327)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:945)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:863)
01-16 16:25:05.915: E/AndroidRuntime(23174):    ... 41 more
```

And the layout from the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.locker.theme.one.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".14"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <DigitalClock
            android:id="@+id/digitalClock"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="66sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".14"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleInverse"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/activateBtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/material_deep_teal_200"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="Test" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the style i use:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.


    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.


        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
        <!-- Main theme colors -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

I did google a bit, but didn't find an idea that could tell me what is happening. Any points would be great. Thank you

Comment: be sure you import the appcompat library correctly. this was the problem for me. I imported again the library and then add it as reference to the project and clean the project at the end.

Comment: @PratikButani: Did you have a closer look and the questions and answers to check whether they are different?

Comment: Yeah @Lii, Its reopened. My mistake was that word `color` and `dimension`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I faced the same issue, that was caused by using `attributes` as a reference to `color` in an XML drawable.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13471695/3212712) on **API < 21** you can't use attrs to `color` in the XML drawable. So only way is to use a reference to a color resource (`@color/YOURS_COLOR`)  or use `#RGB` format.

So if you want to use an XML drawable with theme depended colors you should create a drawable for each theme.

Comment: Does AppCompat help in this?

Comment: @Qamar, no. Bug reproduces with AppCompat.

Comment: Also dynamic gradient based on theme attribute colorPrimary and Dark is not possible in API<21 with AppCompat and it's widgets, also they says we replace all views with AppCompat alternative, Google didn't resolve this yet? I created multiple gradient drawables but I think I need to create different layerLists for different themes. Still crash and says `Can't convert to color: type=0x2 error`

Comment: Check this out, Loading layer list using `ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.welcome_logo_layers);` it has `<item android:id="@+id/logo_gradient" android:drawable="?attr/logo_gradient" />` and declare in theme `<item name="logo_gradient">@drawable/logo_gradient_t1</item>`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on API 10 devices and it was caused by using theme for API 11+ (from appcompat).
For quick solution you may find the following themes declaration in **styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="...">
...
<style name="AppTheme" parent="...">
```

And change on:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
...
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
```

Comment: when I do this I get the following error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Comment: @maysi You can only use an `AppCompat` theme with an `AppCompatActivity`, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Change "AppTheme" to not use Material. For example try:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">

</style>
```

I had a very similar issue on my Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro 8.4 Running Android 4.2. It worked when I changed Styles.xml to use "android:Theme.Holo" or "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar".

I haven't been able to find any information on exactly why this happens, and why it seems to only affect Samsung products. If you really want to include Material as a style, you could try adding another style file to use with devices that have API level 21 or higher. More info on that is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) under the section "Select a theme based on platform version"

Please keep us updated if you find any other fixes.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when using 3rd party lib https://github.com/hoang8f/android-flat-button after I upgraded gradle to 3.0.1.

Not ideal, but downgrading gradle seemed to resolve the error

This change requires updating 2 files:

1. Project **build.gradle** with

   `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3`
2. **gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties** with

   `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip`