# loginInputText.setError("erreur"); gives me an error

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I am trying to show an error under my edit text, like the one used in the Material design:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/login_login_input_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/login_login_input_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/login_edit_text_background"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/icone_info"
                android:drawablePadding="2dp"
                android:hint="@string/login"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

i've tried using `loginInputText.setError("error");`

and

`loginInputLayout.setError("error");`

And it does not seem to work, i've seen in stack that i need to implement:

`loginInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);`

But whenever i try to use it i get this error (it's the same error when i try to use the `setError` alone :

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: 475, PID: 9466
              android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class TextView
```

**EDIT:**

i get my logininputlayout and my logininputtext by :

```
 loginInputText = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.login_login_input_text);
```

**EDIT2:**

all the dependencies are there :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
```

**EDIT 3:**
Once i add the `app:errorEnabled` i get this error :

```
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #83: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

**EDIT 4:**

My app theme already uses `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` and my activity also inherits `AppCompatActivity`

**EDIT 5:**

if i try to use a normal `EditText`i get this error :`android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class TextView`

**EDIT 6:**

This is the theme of my layout:

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">

    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorLoginGray</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorLoginBlack</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorTextInputGray</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorLoginBlack</item>
</style>
```

**Edit 7:**
**Solution**

add a second theme and extend the main theme from `AppCompat`:

```
     <style name="TextLabel" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorLoginGray</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorLoginBlack</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorTextInputGray</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorLoginBlack</item>
</style>

<style name="TextLabelError" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/errorRed</item>

</style>
```

and in the xml :

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/login_login_input_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/TextLabelError"
            >
```

Comment: Hello, see [similar post] 
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578976/android-textinputfield-inflator-error)

[One more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958972/inflateexception-with-textinputlayout-and-alertdialog)

[Or sample]
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953449/design-android-edittext-to-show-error-message-as-described-by-google)

Comment: How are you getting your loginInputLayout?

Comment: this is the problem , i have all the dependencies and used the exact same instructions and it does not work , i've read them all

Comment: see my edits, i've updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextInputLayout`

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/userPasswordTIL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:paddingLeft="17dp"
                android:paddingRight="17dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and then

```
userPasswordTIL = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.userPasswordTIL);
userPasswordTIL.setError("Required"); #1 pic result

             OR

userPasswordTIL.getEditText().setError("Required"); #2 pic result
```

[image: #1 result][image: #2 result]

Comment: thank you for you answer i've tried it but I get the same error when i use a normal EditText.

Comment: Normal editText? You just wrote the code of TextInputLayout above.

Comment: @Farhan yes the normal `<EditText>` i've tried it take a look at my edit

Comment: change theme of `TextInputLayout`. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @Kingofkech Use `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat ` in `TextInputLayout` and try

Comment: Thank you , i now get the error message to show never the less i get this error while pressing the button:` Failed to inflate ColorStateList, leaving it to the framework`

Comment: Follow up with this answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44692217/failed-to-inflate-colorstatelist-leaving-it-to-the-framework-java-lang-unsuppor)

Comment: Thank you for your time sir , you helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:errorEnabled="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter your name" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and

```
TextInputLayout til = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.text_input_layout);
til.setError("Text");
```

Comment: already seen this answer in an other post and it does not work , once i add `the app:errorEnabled` i get this error : `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #83: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`

Comment: +1, Since API 26 it's better to put hint and inputType to TextInputLayout for Autofill Framework, in other case you can get NPE because of this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67675432

Comment: @Kingofkech app:errorEnabled is optional, if you go to source you can find that whenever you call setError("error") method it sets errorEnabled to true

Comment: just change the theme and check android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"

Comment: or try this ans  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958972/inflateexception-with-textinputlayout-and-alertdialog