# android.view.InflateException when using selectableItemBackground

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-attributes

When inflating my layout, I get this exception:

```
E AndroidRuntime: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
E AndroidRuntime:        at com.myapp.view.MyRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyRecyclerAdapter:80)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5288)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4551)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4461)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1962)
```

There is no "Caused by" in the log, but I added code to catch the exception and call `getCause()` until it returns null, and here is the sequence of events:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>
Error: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v11/selectable_list_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020096
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0100f9 a=-1}
```

0x7f020096 is `selectable_list_background` (see below), and the TypedValue it references is `?selectableItemBackground`.

I narrowed the exception down to my use of `?selectableItemBackground`. More specifically, I'm using a CardView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foreground="@drawable/selectable_list_background"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    >
```

And this the relevant part of `drawable/selectable_list_background`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="?selectableItemBackground" />
</selector>
```

This activity is using my own theme, its parent is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.

This code used to work, but I just dug up this code after a few months, and now it crashes with the exception. My guess is that this is related to upgrading the support library to 23.0.1 and target SDK to 23, but I haven't switched back to 22 yet to verify that.

It all works fine if I remove the one line referencing `?selectableItemBackground`. I also tried `?attr/selectableItemBackground` and `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground`, but got the same results. (The latter makes me believe that it may not be a problem with the support library).

**EDIT:**

I looked at it in the debugger, and I have a suspicion that it is this code in `android.content.res.Resources`, inside `loadDrawable()`:

```
Drawable loadDrawable(TypedValue value, int id, Theme theme) throws NotFoundException {
    [...]
    dr = loadDrawableForCookie(value, id, null);
```

Note that this function takes a theme, but doesn't pass it in when calling `loadDrawableForCookie()`, which is the method that eventually triggers the first exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0100f9 a=-1}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:867)
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:170)
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:115)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1215)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1124)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2630)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4280)
```

This code seems to be new to Android 6.0 - the 5.0 code is quite different, but the theme is passed in when loading the drawable. And the theme is necessary AFAICT - the attribute in question is part of `AppCompat`, so it needs the activity's theme to resolve it.

That seems like a blatant bug though, so I'm not convinced that I'm on the right track here. Any ideas?

Comment: Which is the parent theme you used for AppTheme?

Comment: @FabinPaul Sorry, I should have mentioned that. The parent theme is     `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.

Comment: Did you try using the parent theme Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light

Comment: Tried that (of course adjusting `windowActionBar` and `windowNoTitle`), but that has the same exception when inflating, with the same stack trace.

Comment: "My guess is that this is related to upgrading the support library to 23.0.1 and target SDK to 23, but I haven't switched back to 22 yet to verify that." You are right, I had the same problem and needed to switch to version 22 back again. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376766/unable-to-start-activity-componentinfo-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml/37380072#37380072)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official answer - you can't use theme attributes for `android:drawable` or `android:src` attributes. Simply not possible, by design. There's another answer that explores the same issue and offers a solution: [How to reference style attributes from a drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041537/how-to-reference-style-attributes-from-a-drawable/13471695#13471695)

In my case, I couldn't really do that since AppCompat's `?selectableItemBackground` references a private drawable. So I opted for a code solution - I'm setting the foreground to `?selectableItemBackground` while the card is not selected, and to my own state list drawable once I'm in selection mode.

This is a very ugly solution, so ugly that I'm not going to share the code here, but the best I could come up with so far. If somebody has a better solution, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Are you sure, you used your `Activity` as the `Context` for inflating and not the `ApplicationContext`?

Comment: Thanks! Wrong context can be a reason of fail too

Comment: @ArtjomKönig You saved my day.

Answer (score 7):

As @Artjom says problem is with passing `application context` while creating custom view. I was also facing the same issue and I was passing `getApplicationContext()` instead of the `activity` as `context`. After passing `Activity` as a `context` problem resolved.

Hope it might help to someone else.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error when using the androidx Fragment Testing component. By default  `launchFragmentInContainer()` uses the theme `FragmentScenarioEmptyFragmentActivityTheme`, resulting in the error.

Simple fix is to use your own theme which extends AppCompat:

`launchFragmentInContainer(theme = R.style.AppTheme)`

Comment: That's exactly the context I was looking for and worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, other answers are not my case. The way to work for me is to check if your activity uses AppCompat theme style:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

Then use AppCompat theme in your activity (in many ways, but I show the way to use Manifest):

```
<application
        android:name=".Abbott"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- Any configuration inside -->

</application>
```