# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm having a problem in my Android in versions 5.x, not reproducible in Android 4.3.

When starting a PreferenceActivity, the following error appears:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.xxxx.yyyy/com.xxxx.yyyy.view.SettingsActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML
>   file line #31: Error inflating class

I've surfed the web for reasons but they say the error may happen for several, different reasons, no clue what's happening exactly and no way to narrow the problem.

If I empty the preferences.xml the error is there, if I start a different, DummyActivity (blank activity) it happens again, so the error may be... elsewhere in the application!!

The caller activity is a map activity; I've read that this could be a problem but I'm starting it using the latest documentation available:

```
((SupportMapFragment) mContext.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
                    mMap = map;
                    setUpMap();
                }
            });
```

Using getSupportFragmentManager and async calls.

Any ideas? I cannot just search throughout the whole app looking for this error! Android should provide more human-readable info for this kind of issues... specially when they don't happen in every Android version, which is another question: why compatibility is so broken so often.

Comment: Please share your entire logcat. There is more to that exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using my source control system I did a binary search (sigh) to find the changeset where the bug appears for the first time and it matches when I update the sdk target version to **API 23 (Android 6.0, permissions change)** everything is **broken**:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
}
```

I've searched and there are **more people with the same problem**, so it seems to me that **there's a bug in sdk tools version 23.0.1 (latest)**. The issue is that I cannot update to API version 23 and check permissions properly as Android 6 handles them, but I can do little to workaround this, the API tools just don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Mention `android:name = "com.packagename.Activityname"` in your xml file.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:name="com.packagename.Activityname"/>
```

Comment: Luckily I use a source control version tool on my own, so I'm doing binary search to figure out what broke the change. I'm suspicious about applying some Lint advice, it wouldn't be the first time.... you must be careful when applying what Lint says, sometimes the suggestions don't apply well to your case :(