# Android < sdk 21 giving InflateException

Tags: android, android-compatibility

I'm using a state list drawable to select and deselect an item row inside a RecyclerView but it throws me an exception on < 21 devices.

Style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/my_color</item>
  </style>
```

My item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="68dp"
    android:background="@drawable/item_sound"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

  </LinearLayout>
```

Selector drawable `drawable/item_sound.xml`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@color/my_color" android:state_selected="true" />
  <item android:drawable="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" android:state_selected="false" />
</selector>
```

Exception:

```
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.test.app.android, PID: 11391
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.test.app.android.logged.top.TopSongsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(TopSongsAdapter.java:28)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.test.app.android.logged.top.TopSongsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(TopSongsAdapter.java:17)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5223)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4449)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4359)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1370)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:562)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2900)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14818)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14818)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:581)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14818)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1037)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:747)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:761)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14818)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14818)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14818)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout.onLayout(SlidingUpPanelLayout.java:860)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14818)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14818)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14818)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14818)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14818)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
11-13 15:13:09.533 11391-11391/? E/AndroidRuntime:  at android.widget.FrameLayo
```

I think that is related to `<item android:drawable="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" android:state_selected="false" />`
 but I can't find why

Why?

**--------  EDIT -----------**

Already tried with `"?attr/selectableItemBackground"`and `"?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` and nothing.

Comment: Could you post the XML that loads a `FrameLayout`? Unless `FrameLayo` is your problem

Answer (score 0):

[look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13471695/4937232)

seems like its not possible to use theme attributes for `android:drawable` or `android:src`

Comment: Nope, `Theme.AppCompat` app compat theme have it

Comment: so sorry wasnt notice that.

Comment: is item_sound is your selector?

Comment: yeah item_sound.xml is the drawable, I updated the question

Comment: is the exception has "Caused by:" line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95083/discussion-between-danielgomezrico-and-alinpha).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a drawable for v21 and another for < 21.

`attributes in selectors didn't exist prior to API 21. At all. You can certainly create two different selectors, one in drawable and one in drawable-v21﻿`