# How to obtain a themed drawable in code before API Level 21?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources, android-context

I want to use `Context` or `Resources` to obtain a themed drawable, and my `minSDK` is 15. How do I go about doing it?

The [developer documentation for Resources](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int)) has a note which says,

> Note: To obtain a themed drawable, use Context.getDrawable(int) or getDrawable(int, Theme) passing the desired theme.

Both `Context.getDrawable(int)` and `Resources.getDrawable(int, Theme)` were added in API 21, so I can't use them. If I look at [ResourcesCompat documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat.html#getDrawable(android.content.res.Resources, int, android.content.res.Resources.Theme)), it has a similar limitation:

> Prior to API level 21, the theme will not be applied and this method simply calls through to getDrawable(int).

Is there really no way to obtain a themed drawable before API level 21?

I can provide sample code if required, but it's really just an `attrs.xml` which specifies the attribute, `themes.xml` which defines that attribute, `ContextThemeWrapper` which applies it, and a `drawable/foobar.xml` which uses `<solid android:color="?attr/MY_ATTRIBUTE" />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting the question, I found out that you can't use `?attr/` in drawable XML files before API level 21. See [How to reference style attributes from a drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041537/how-to-reference-style-attributes-from-a-drawable) for more details.