# Drawable not working on API 19

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I added a FastScroller to my RecyclerView and used a "Bubble"-Drawable.

If I test my App on API 21, it works but if I test it on API 19, it crashes:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{at.guger.musixs/at.guger.musixs.ui.MainActivity}:
>
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error
>   inflating class at.guger.fastscroll.FastScroller
>   ... 
>   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15:
>   Error inflating class at.guger.fastscroll.FastScroller
>
> ... Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> ... Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class at.guger.fastscroll.FastScrollBubble
>
> ... 
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> ... 
>   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/bubble.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02004b
>
> at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3457)
>
> at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
>
> at android.view.View.(View.java:3767)
>
> at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:481)
>
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.(FrameLayout.java:101)
>
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.(FrameLayout.java:97)
>
> at at.guger.fastscroll.FastScrollBubble.(FastScrollBubble.java:0)
>
> ... 38

My Bubble-XML-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/bubble_corner_radius"
        android:topRightRadius="@dimen/bubble_corner_radius"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/bubble_corner_radius"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" />

    <solid android:color="?attr/colorAccent" />

    <size
        android:height="@dimen/bubble_size"
        android:width="@dimen/bubble_size" />
</shape>
```

My FastScroll-Bubble-Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fastscroll_bubble"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bubble"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    tools:text="A"
    tools:visibility="visible" />
```

My Folder-Structure:

[image]

Comment: no my xml file is in the default drawable folder, like you can see

Comment: I think that there is a tag which is not compatible or something...

Comment: you are using a third party library, you should open an issue on the author GitHub providing the scenario and some info on how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: the library is made by myself ;)

Comment: ohh sorry ! Is it open source ? It would be easier to inspect some code...

Comment: no I only made it to use it in my app, but the problem is solved, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is the usage of `?attr/` in your drawable

```
<solid android:color="?attr/colorAccent" />
```

This is only supported from Lollipop up. So for all versions below you need to define the color directly as color resource.

```
<solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
```

See [How to reference style attributes from a drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041537/how-to-reference-style-attributes-from-a-drawable) for more detailed information.

Comment: Oh thanks! I was scared I have to rebuild the whole fastscroller but this was easy :D