# Unable to add attribute primary color in android drawable xml

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, android-styles

I have my theme defined as

```
<style name="AppThemeRed" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryRed</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDarkRed</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccentRed</item>
    </style>
```

In my XML layouts, I am doing

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/topBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```

Whenever I change any theme the colorPrimary changes

However, if I have the same thing added in drawable e.g

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

It crashes with unable to inflate view, the view which has background set as `@drawabe/xxxx`

How can I define theme color attribute in my XML drawable

Comment: Please post your stack trace.

Comment: do you get any `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line`... ex?

Comment: @Charuka yes same error

Comment: we cannot use `android:color` in <item>, we need to use `android:drawable` to  set background,

Comment: @Charuka the problem is how to define attributed color to drawable since i am changing themes and for each theme there is a separate color. In layout xml it works but in drawable xml it doesn't

Comment: @MuhammadUmar i told you way of defining attributed color in drawble in my answer ... use it as you want

Comment: @Muhammad Umar check mine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just replace...

```
android:color="?attr/colorPrimary"
```

to...

```
android:color="@color/colorPrimaryRed"
```

**Update**

It is not possible to reference an attribute in an xml drawable below API 21.
In order to make your theme you need to:

Create one xml drawable per theme.
Include the needed color into you drawable directly with the @color tag or #RGB format.

Make an attribute for your drawable in attrs.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Attributes must be lowercase as we want to use them for drawables -->
    <attr name="my_drawable" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

Add your drawable to your theme.xml.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
   <item name="my_drawable">@drawable/my_drawable</item>
</style>
```

Reference your drawable in your layout using your attribute.

```
<TextView android:background="?my_drawable" />
```

Comment: i dont want to do that :)

Comment: @Abi do u see the selector xml, thats what i want to change, The layout xml already works fine.

Comment: android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" this WORKS, <solid android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" /> this doesn't

Comment: @MuhammadUmar try `?colorPrimary` or `?android:colorPrimary`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be supported on API 21+. Below that you cannot reference an attribute in drawable. 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26251.

This might help for workarounds: 
[How to reference style attributes from a drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041537/how-to-reference-style-attributes-from-a-drawable)

Comment: the workaround says its for 21+ API. my minimum is 16

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041537/how-to-reference-style-attributes-from-a-drawable

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try

```
<solid android:color="@android:attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

instead of

```
<solid android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

Comment: Doesn't work mate. First one is obviously 21+ and other one is what i am doing and getting a crash

Answer (score 0):

You can use :-

```
<solid android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"  />
```