# Error inflating class when using android:color="?android:colorBackground"

Tags: android, android-studio, background-color

This drawable creates a diagonal cut background:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <item android:top="170dp"
        android:bottom="-100dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="-300dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-10"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="100%">
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid
                    android:color="?android:colorBackground"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

In Android Studio, the view works, but after `RUN` it does not work on mobile.

Errorlog :

> `android.view.InflateException`: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class `<unknown>`

How can I fix it?

Comment: there is no way to reference theme/style attribute from XML drawable on pre-Lollipop devices, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041537/how-to-reference-style-attributes-from-a-drawable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference style attributes from a drawable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041537/how-to-reference-style-attributes-from-a-drawable)

Comment: Can you help me more ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using theme references in XML drawables requires API level 21 (current min is lower 21)

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem and i solved it by passing color code instead of `android:color="?android:colorBackground"`

```
<solid
    android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
```

and worked for me...